# How to hide/show an animated svg depending on active tab?

Tags: html, css, svg, tabs

Fiddle and snippet bellow : https://jsfiddle.net/e130kr2x/

I want the svg to animate when one of my tab is active (achieved) and to not display or fade out when I open a new tab (not achieved). This new tab will now be active and animate the svg and so on (achieved).

-- First question : I did copy the svg in my html for every tab. Is there a way to do this only in css instead of copying the svg in every tab ? I thought about the image attribute but it does not support animation.

-- Second question : I have the svg animate under every active tab but it is staying under inactive tabs. How to make it not display or fade out when tab becomes inactive ?

Also, kinda off topic, but if someone can show me how to move my js script in a js file instead of the html file, I'd be grateful. I'm still new to js. Thank you for your suggestions.

```css
#my-tab{
`      margin-top:20px;
   overflow:hidden;
   display:block;}

#my-tab ul.tabs{
   display:block;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   list-style-type:none;}

#my-tab ul.tabs > li{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   margin-bottom:0;
   padding:0;
   width:17%}

#my-tab ul.tabs li a{
    font-size:15px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin:0;
    padding:7px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#303030;}

.flex2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    padding: 0 10px;}
 
 
 /* SVG ANIMATION bELLOW */
 
 #my-tab ul.tabs li a.active path {
  
     stroke:#6594F6;
     fill:#6594F6;
     stroke-dasharray:330;
     opacity:1;
     animation: animate 3s cubic-bezier(.27,.6,.8,.77);}

@keyframes animate {
  
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    fill:none;
    stroke-dashoffset:330;  
  }
  
  30% {
    opacity:1;
    fill:none;
    stroke-dashoffset:330;  
  }
  
  90% {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0);
   }
  
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    stroke-dashoffset:0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("ul.tabs").each(function(){var t,i,a=$(this).find("a");t=a.first().addClass("active"),i=$(t.attr("href")),a.not(":first").each(function(){$($(this).attr("href")).hide()}),$(this).find("a").click(function(a){return t.removeClass("active"),i.hide(),t=$(this),i=$($(this).attr("href")),t.addClass("active"),i.show(),!1})})});</script>

<div class="product-description" itemprop="description">

<div id="my-tab" class="my-tab">

 <ul class="tabs">
      <div class="flex2">
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span class="tab1 text-link1">
        
        
        Description
          
          
           <svg version="1.1" class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 148.1 30.3" enable-background="new 0 0 148.1 30.3" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M-260.1-275.3c20.9-13.8,44.3-23,68.9-27.2c12.7-2.2,26-3,38.8-1.8c13.3,1.3,25.3,8.2,38.1,11.6
   c40.1,10.5,84.9-0.9,115.5-28.6c1.4-1.3-0.7-3.4-2.1-2.1c-32.7,29.7-81,39.3-122.7,24.8c-5.8-2-11.5-4.5-17.4-6.3
   c-6.2-1.9-12.6-2.5-19.1-2.7c-11.9-0.4-23.8,0.8-35.4,2.9c-23.6,4.3-46.2,13.6-66.2,26.9C-263.2-276.8-261.7-274.2-260.1-275.3
   L-260.1-275.3z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M7,17.4c9.2,3.6,20.1,1.3,26-6.9c1.2-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.1-1c-6.9,5.1-0.8,12.6,5.1,14.6
   c4.2,1.4,9,0.8,13.2,0.4c6.3-0.7,12.5-1.9,18.6-3.2c23.9-5,49.1-12.4,72.4-1.3c1.2,0.6,6.7-0.4,4.6-1.6
   c-16.1-9.9-35.3-9.8-53.3-6.8c-11.2,1.8-22.1,4.9-33.2,7.3c-5.4,1.1-10.9,2.2-16.4,2.5c-5,0.3-12-6.3-6.4-10.6
   c-1.7-0.3-3.4-0.6-5.1-1c-3.9,5.4-10.4,8.4-16.9,5.9C9.4,15.3,4.4,16.4,7,17.4L7,17.4z"/>
 </g>
      </g>
  </svg>                 
          </span></a></li>
          
          
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal truckicon-black"></i>
        
        Livraison
          
          <svg version="1.1" class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 148.1 30.3" enable-background="new 0 0 148.1 30.3" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M-260.1-275.3c20.9-13.8,44.3-23,68.9-27.2c12.7-2.2,26-3,38.8-1.8c13.3,1.3,25.3,8.2,38.1,11.6
   c40.1,10.5,84.9-0.9,115.5-28.6c1.4-1.3-0.7-3.4-2.1-2.1c-32.7,29.7-81,39.3-122.7,24.8c-5.8-2-11.5-4.5-17.4-6.3
   c-6.2-1.9-12.6-2.5-19.1-2.7c-11.9-0.4-23.8,0.8-35.4,2.9c-23.6,4.3-46.2,13.6-66.2,26.9C-263.2-276.8-261.7-274.2-260.1-275.3
   L-260.1-275.3z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M7,17.4c9.2,3.6,20.1,1.3,26-6.9c1.2-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.1-1c-6.9,5.1-0.8,12.6,5.1,14.6
   c4.2,1.4,9,0.8,13.2,0.4c6.3-0.7,12.5-1.9,18.6-3.2c23.9-5,49.1-12.4,72.4-1.3c1.2,0.6,6.7-0.4,4.6-1.6
   c-16.1-9.9-35.3-9.8-53.3-6.8c-11.2,1.8-22.1,4.9-33.2,7.3c-5.4,1.1-10.9,2.2-16.4,2.5c-5,0.3-12-6.3-6.4-10.6
   c-1.7-0.3-3.4-0.6-5.1-1c-3.9,5.4-10.4,8.4-16.9,5.9C9.4,15.3,4.4,16.4,7,17.4L7,17.4z"/>
 </g>
      </g>
  </svg>        
          
          
    </a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3"><span class="tab4">
    
    
    Nos avantages
          
          <svg version="1.1" class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 148.1 30.3" enable-background="new 0 0 148.1 30.3" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M-260.1-275.3c20.9-13.8,44.3-23,68.9-27.2c12.7-2.2,26-3,38.8-1.8c13.3,1.3,25.3,8.2,38.1,11.6
   c40.1,10.5,84.9-0.9,115.5-28.6c1.4-1.3-0.7-3.4-2.1-2.1c-32.7,29.7-81,39.3-122.7,24.8c-5.8-2-11.5-4.5-17.4-6.3
   c-6.2-1.9-12.6-2.5-19.1-2.7c-11.9-0.4-23.8,0.8-35.4,2.9c-23.6,4.3-46.2,13.6-66.2,26.9C-263.2-276.8-261.7-274.2-260.1-275.3
   L-260.1-275.3z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <g>
  <path fill="#6594F6" d="M7,17.4c9.2,3.6,20.1,1.3,26-6.9c1.2-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.1-1c-6.9,5.1-0.8,12.6,5.1,14.6
   c4.2,1.4,9,0.8,13.2,0.4c6.3-0.7,12.5-1.9,18.6-3.2c23.9-5,49.1-12.4,72.4-1.3c1.2,0.6,6.7-0.4,4.6-1.6
   c-16.1-9.9-35.3-9.8-53.3-6.8c-11.2,1.8-22.1,4.9-33.2,7.3c-5.4,1.1-10.9,2.2-16.4,2.5c-5,0.3-12-6.3-6.4-10.6
   c-1.7-0.3-3.4-0.6-5.1-1c-3.9,5.4-10.4,8.4-16.9,5.9C9.4,15.3,4.4,16.4,7,17.4L7,17.4z"/>
 </g>
      </g>
  </svg>        
          
          </span></a></li>
      </div>
      
      
        <div id="tab-1">

          I'm the first

        </div>

         <div id="tab-2">

          I'm number 2
          
          </div>

         <div id="tab-3">

          I'm the last one. 

        </div>   
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change the `display` property based on whether the tab has the `.active` class, like this:

```
<style>
  #my-tab ul.tabs li a svg {
    display: none;
  }
  #my-tab ul.tabs li a.active svg  {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>
```